# What is etched half fiducial in PCB stencil ? How to use it?

Tags: pcb, stencil, fiducial

On pcb manufacturer website, it is possible to opt for "etched half fiducial".

Here is how it is explained :

> Fiducial Mark is an alignment mark for surface mount assembly
> machines.In General,machine assembly must have Fiducial marks.Fiducial
> marks are unnecessary when you are placing your parts by hand.
>
> [image]

.

It's a bit unclear and I can't found any relevant information on the net.

What is exactly etched half fiducial ? Do you have picture or video ?

How to use it ?

How to design the board/stencil for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, whenever it is important to work with extreme precision while precisely positioning very small parts (for example, working with  fine-pitch components) or to align vertically different masks or layers (for example, for manufacturing multilayer boards, or to align a stencil to a PB), automatic optical alignment-based machines are necessary.
Just to reduce or to oppose the impact of the unavoidable dimensional tolerances (always present in manufatured parts), these high-precision machines need to be based on the optical alignments, referred to some specific locations/areas, both on the parts to be worked, and on the tools/templates used by manufacturing machines.
These locations, marked in different way (circle, dots or even crossed lines, according to the machines used) are called **fiducials** in the PCB's jargon, and their number & locations will tightly depend from the targeted precision of the manufacturing process.

In the case of solder paste printing process in PCB assembly, having to deposit very controlled volumes of solder paste on small (and  very near) pads, the stencil is designed with its own referenced fiducials, in order to permit the alignment of the apertures on the stencil with the solder pads on the PCB, that is, by aligning the fiducials on the stencil with respect to the fiducials on the PB (effectively, in the case of high-precision solder printing machines, a top-bottom view camera is provided, in order to align the two parts).

And, since you don't want to deposit solder paste on the board fiducials , otherwise you will ruin/damage them, the fiducials on the stencil must be ***closed*** on the top (in order to block the solder paste release), and ***visible*** on the back,  that is, practically they need to be half-etched in the stencil.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on an automatic Pick and Place assembly machine. Fiducials are round or cross-shaped signs that are placed on the corners of printed circuit boards or on panels with many PCBs for alignment in the presence of any offset. Before mounting the machine visually searches for this marker and recalculates the coordinates of the components to be mounted. You usually need 2 markers placed diagonally. If they are missing, small through holes on the board can be used instead.
Fiducials are also used in stencils for the same purpose - to check the location. Stencils are used for applying solder paste. Where there are holes, the paste passes from there. Obviously, half-etched holes(fiducials) are used only as markers and the passage of the paste is undesirable, so they are half-etched.

Comment: And do you know what an "**etched half** fiducial" is? I'm curious about that, too.